# Remove MathReview number in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

When using the "amsplain" style in BibTeX, it automatically prints MathReview MR numbers in the citation. For example if the citation entry looks like:

```
@book {Babook,
 AUTHOR = {Baldwin, John T.},
 TITLE = {Fundamentals of stability theory},
 SERIES = {Perspectives in Mathematical Logic},
 PUBLISHER = {Springer-Verlag},
 ADDRESS = {Berlin},
 YEAR = {1988},
 PAGES = {xiv+447},
 ISBN = {3-540-15298-9},
 MRCLASS = {03-02 (03C45)},
 MRNUMBER = {918762 (89k:03002)},
 MRREVIEWER = {John B. Goode},
}
```

Then MRNUMBER is printed in the citation (but not MRCLASS or MRREVIEWER).

I would like to stop this from happening, i.e. prevent the MRNUMBER from being printed in the citation. [This](http://www.math.uh.edu/~torok/math_6298/latex/bibtex.html) website suggests adding

```
@preamble{"\providecommand{\MR}[1]{}"}
```

to the beginning of the *.bib file. But this did not work for me. The other suggestion is to edit the amsplain.bst file.

Can someone tell me how to edit the amsplain.bst file so that the MRNUMBER is not printed? Alternatively, is there some other way to accomplish this?

Note: I would like to avoid individually deleting the MRNUMBER from each entry in my reference file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the command added with `@preamble` is good, except that if the document class
you are using already defines `\MR`, it won't be overwritten by what's specified
by a `\providecommand`.

you can override *all* "predefinitions" by adding this to the preamble of your
document, as late in the preamble as you can manage:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
   \def\MR#1{}
}
```

it could be done more subtly, of course, by first checking whether a definition
for `\MR` already exists, and using `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand` as appropriate,
but i haven't got time to test that right now.  (i've also forgotten whether one
`#` is enough, or two are needed; none of the "usual" manuals bother to mention that.)

Comment: Wow, that's a lot more elegant than the answer I was about to write down, which would involve editing (a copy of) the file `amsplain.bst`!

Comment: @Mico -- i *have* edited `amsplain.bst`, which is why i prefer a "more direct" approach if one exists.  (if you want to insert the code to `\if` the situation, or confirm whether one or two `#` are needed, please feel free.)

Comment: Your code is fine -- nothing for me to edit. :-)

Comment: oh, it works all right, but "it's not latex".  and i meant that if you wanted to put in an `\if` test for whether `\MR` was already defined, some people would prefer that manner of expression.

Comment: Since the purpose of the instruction is to make sure the `\MR` macro does nothing, I think there's little to be gained from checking first if the macro has been defined -- and clobbering it only if it's been defined. If `\MR` for some reason has *not* been defined, I see no harm in going ahead anyway and defining it to do nothing.

Comment: ah, well.  purists say that `\def` is a bludgeon (or a primitive, which it is).  they prefer scalpels.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! I should have noticed that MR numbers appear with the \MR command in the bbl file, but I didn't until I read this great answer.